# Laravel Collection keys modification

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I use `filter` method from `Collection` class to remove some objects from collection. But after that operation, sometimes objects with keys eg. 1, 4, 5 left. I would like to always have elements with order 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. after `filter` action.

Is there any elegant way to do it without rewriting table to a new one?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps use the Collection's `values()` method to reset the keys?

Answer (score 85):

You can use Laravel Collection's [`values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-values) method to make the the keys of a collection in a serialized order like this:

```
// Just for demonstration
$collection = collect([
    10 => ['fruit' => 'Apple', 'price' => 200],
    11 => ['fruit' => 'Mango', 'price' => 500]
]);

$values = $collection->values();

$values->all();

/* Result would be:
    [
        0 => ['fruit' => 'Apple', 'price' => 200],
        1 => ['fruit' => 'Mango', 'price' => 500],
    ]
*/
```

Comment: +1 Thanks man, recently came on this resetting array issue when returning an collection array of various connections.

Comment: This is exactly what I was needed for my select2 params array.  Thank you.